# Efficiently Parse HTML Table

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I have a large table I need to convert from HTML to Access. I'm unable to use the built in Import tool due to authentication restrictions. However I can automate logging into the website using `Microsoft internet controls` then grab the table from html with `HTML Object Library`. Then I can run through the raw HTML text or the Objects and build my table. But it still takes too long. The text is about a million characters. Maybe there isn't a faster way?

Here is what I've been using to break up the text. I assumed using the HTML objects directly would be slower still.

```
Sub CopyTable()
Dim HTML As String
HTML = Tbl.innerHTML
Dim grid()
ReDim grid(0 To UBound(Split(HTML, "<tr")) - 1, 0 To 100)
Dim xline As Double
Dim poss As Double
poss = 1
xline = -1
xitem = 0
Do While poss <= Len(HTML)
    Select Case Mid(HTML, poss, 3)
        Case "<td":
            poss = InStr(poss, HTML, ">")
            grid(xline, xitem) = Mid(HTML, poss + 1, InStr(poss, HTML, "<") - poss - 1)
            xitem = xitem + 1
            poss = InStr(poss + 1, HTML, "<")
        Case "<th":
            If Mid(HTML, poss, 7) = "<thead>" Then
            poss = InStr(poss + 1, HTML, "<")
            Else
            poss = InStr(poss, HTML, ">")
            grid(xline, xitem) = Mid(HTML, poss + 1, InStr(poss, HTML, "<") - poss - 1)
            xitem = xitem + 1
            poss = InStr(poss + 1, HTML, "<")
            End If
        Case "<tr":
            xitem = 0
            xline = xline + 1
            poss = InStr(poss, HTML, ">")
        Case Else:
            poss = poss + 1
            poss = InStr(poss, HTML, "<")
    End Select
    If Mid(HTML, poss, 2) = "</" Then poss = InStr(poss + 1, HTML, "<")
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: How long is too long? I would try using the HTMLDocument approach: it should be more robust at least.

Comment: If you can get the html, can't you just make a local file and import that through the user interface?

Comment: Thanks for the tips!